# Какой элемент управления выбрать для вмещения блоков текста

Tags: c#, winforms

я новичок в деле виндовс форм и самого сишарпа. Мне нужно сделать форму с элементом в котором должны перечисляться текстовые элементы с соответствующими им кнопками, этот элемент должен уметь прокручиваться снизу вверх и я не могу понять какой именно элемент мне для этого подойдёт или может вообще сможете подсказать как это сделать иначе?
На картинке этот элемент справа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо нужен ListBox в котором будет Label и Button

Comment: Для этой цели можно использовать самые разные компоненты. И `DataGridView`, и `TableLayoutPanel`, и др.